# Mostrar imagen desde la carpeta de un servidor protegido con .htpasswd

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

Tengo una `app` en `android` que muestra imagenes con [este plugin](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). El problema es que he añadido un `.htpasswd` para proteger las imagenes y ahora no me las muestra, he añadido a la `url` el parametros `user:password@` pero ahora me sale un error en la consola:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(tempValues.getImagen(), holder.imagen, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

    }
});
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .delayBeforeLoading(10)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .build();
```

¿Hay alguna forma de añadir el usuario y el password en las opciones del imageLoader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El imageLoader de serie no tiene nada para establecer usuario y clave para carga de URLs.

Tendrás que crearte tu propia clase.

Prueba con esta sacada de [stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586183/accessing-protected-images-in-universal-image-loader/29233984#29233984):

```
 byte[] toEncrypt = (username + ":" + password).getBytes();
        String encryptedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Authorization","Basic "+encryptedCredentials);

    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            ...
            .extraForDownloader(headers)
            .build();
```

Ahora te creas tu propio ImageDownloader:

```
public class AuthDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

    public AuthDownloader(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(String url, Object extra) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = super.createConnection(url, extra);
        Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) extra;
        if (headers != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
                conn.setRequestProperty(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

y le pones la configuración:

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .discCacheExtraOptions(600, 600, CompressFormat.PNG, 75, null)
            .imageDownloader(new AuthDownloader(getApplicationContext()))
            .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```